i18next translations not working on page refresh with dynamic URLs in a React
How can I fix i18next translations not working on page refresh with dynamic URLs in a React ?
when a go to dynamic page where the id setted in the url it is just fine for the first time , then when i refresh the translatin goes away , it just returns back when i refresh in another static page

Could you show the code on how this is being done please? Like the page component where you are using i18next.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
